# Wix + uninstall from control panel + Application running

Tags: wix, controls, panel

I have a Wix solution to install an application. When attempting to uninstall the application from control panel while it is running, a popup is appearing to close the application before continue.

The issues is the message showing in that popup which is suppose to be an uninstall message instead of install message.

The message is "**The following application is running which is need to be close before continuing the install**"

can we customize this default popup and change our message?

Comment: Note this same dialog will be shown during an upgrade, so I would be careful how you reword it. The default wording is correct, even though it is confusing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can modify the FilesInUse and MsiRMFilesInUse dialogs. You can modify them directly or use a GUI editor.

Comment: You can find a list here: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/11/20/WiX-editors

Comment: These editors of no use, since they doesn't have FileInUse dialog to edit.

Comment: They are editors, you have to provide the FileInUse dialog file you want to edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify this default message. Edit `FilesInUse` and `MsiRMFilesInUse` dialogs. You can edit them directly in the .wsx file or use a GUI editor. (The dialogs that you need to edit can be defined either in your .wsx file or come from a predefined WiX UI.)

Using [WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/), you can use a visual designer.

---

You would better change the part of the string to come from a property.

> The following application is running which is need to be close before continuing the [CURRENT_ACTION]

You will set the value of the `CURRENT_ACTION` depending on the mode of installation. You can find an example of doing it in the default WiX dialog set, *the maintenance dialog*: when user selects the mode (Modify, Repair, Remove), a property value is set which is then used on the progress page.